# How to transfer data from one device to another using wifi network in android 2.2

Tags: android

I need to trnasfer data from one android device to another device over wifi network?

Comment: Are you familiar with networking concepts?

Comment: little  bit. Can handle the solutions related to networking

Answer (score 0):

If one device is willing to perform access-point like functionality as part of a portable hotspot, and you select that as a wirelss network on the other, you may achieve a network connection between the two that can be used for custom traffic. Though there are ways the hotspot could be implemented where that would not work. Also of concern, the "client" device will now be sending all of its network traffic through the hotspot device, including not just foreground apps but anything it decides to do in the background.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know to which device you want to transfer the data over network like to mobile device to pc. Suppose  you are trying to send data you need will a continuous socket connection using a thread ... the back end device should accept the socket connection and accept the stream.... 
  consider the frist device as client which will write the stream

```
    Runnable action = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            //create your connection 
            while (true){
                //write your stream here 
            }

        }
    };
    new Thread(action).start();
```

and server side the device will open the stream and read it continuously 
 now in the write your stream code use link the and integrate like the example 
Click [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/)!